# Creating custom ODBC to use with Tableau

Tags: sql, odbc, olap, tableau-api

My company is developing an ODBC driver to access a native database, built internally. 
We would like to plug database OLAP tools like Tableau, for example.

How do I know which calls the SQL tableau performs? 
For example, what SQL query to get the measures and dimensions?
Is the any documentation?

I found only this link:http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/tableau-and-odbc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most companies build their ODBC drivers using the SimbaEngine ODBC SDK.  SimbaEngine is the foundation for most of the ODBC drivers that Tableau connects with including ones like Google, Hive, and Cassandra.  If you use the SimbaEngine SDK to build your custom ODBC driver, we can pretty much guarantee it will not only work with Tableau, but will also work with other products like Excel, QlikView, BusinessObjects, etc.  Using the SimbaEngine SDK, you can build a basic read-only ODBC driver in as little as 5 days.  Also, once you have built your ODBC driver, the SDK allows you to quickly take that and build JDBC and ADO.NET drivers as well.  You can get more information at http://www.simba.com/products/simba-engine-sdk.